# Liquibase not working with mysql autoincrement

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I try to create a new table via a liquibase changeset that looks like:

```
    <createTable tableName="mytable">
        <column name="id" type="number" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="description" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="image_path" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
```

this fails with following error:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE 
kkm.mytable (id numeric AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NULL, description 
             VARCHAR(255) NULL, image_path VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
             CONSTRAINT PK_BOUFFE PRIMARY KEY (id)): 
Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'
```

if I set autoIncrement="false", this works perfectly.

Is this a known issue ?

**EDIT:**

this is working:

```
    <createTable tableName="mytable">
        <column name="id" type="number" autoIncrement="false">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="description" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="image_path" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>

    <addAutoIncrement
            columnDataType="int"
            columnName="id"
            incrementBy="1"
            startWith="1"
            tableName="mytable"/>
```

Comment: There is one difference I can spot. In the upper example (that does not work) you set the type to `number`. In the one beneath the type is `int`. So did you try to set the type to `int`? Also, the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) also says "...Use a large enough integer data type for the AUTO_INCREMENT column..." So maybe it has to be an integer?

Comment: @Jens indeed that was the problem, I found it as well yesterday and was going to post an answer thanks

Comment: Note: type="number" should be fixed in later versions of liquibase. 3.0.7+ I believe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change type=**"number"** to type=**"BIGINT"**.

i,e

```
 <createTable tableName="mytable">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="description" type="varchar(255)"/>
        <column name="image_path" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
```

Hope it works..!!!!